# Struggling with a function that should return a total dollar amount

Tags: python

I need to create a function that returns a total of dollar amount. The problem is that I have no clue about how to exactly do this. I've tried to put in some code, but I don't believe it will return what I am looking for:

```
def main():
    pennies = get_input("Enter pennies : ")
    nickels = get_input("Enter nickels : ")
    dimes = get_input("Enter dimes : ")
    quarters = get_input("Enter quarters : ")

    print("You entered : ")
    print("\tPennies  : " , pennies)
    print("\tNickels  : " , nickels)
    print("\tDimes    : " , dimes)
    print("\tQuarters : " , quarters)

    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars = get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)

    print("Total = $", total_value, sep="")
    print("You have", dollars, "dollars and", left_over_cents, "cent(s)")

def get_input(currency):
    currency = 0
    if currency < 0:
        print('Cannot have negative money')
    else:
        return currency

def get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    (pennies * .01) + (nickels * .05) + (dimes * .10) + (quarters * .25)

def get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):

main()
```

Comment: Your get_input function will return zero every time.

Comment: `get_dollars` is not even finished, what is it supposed to do? there is no `get_input`, it is either `input` for `python 3` or `raw_input` for `python 2`

Comment: possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 cannot figure out why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684834/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-cannot-figure-out-why)

Answer (score 1):

Your prints are incorrect, and instead of `get_input` you should use `raw_input`

```
 def main():
    pennies = raw_input("Enter pennies : ")
    nickels = raw_input("Enter nickels : ")
    dimes = raw_input("Enter dimes : ")
    quarters = raw_input("Enter quarters : ")

    print("You entered : ")
    print("\tPennies  : %s" % pennies)
    print("\tNickels  : %s" % nickels)
    print("\tDimes    :  %s" % dimes)
    print("\tQuarters :  %s" % quarters)


    total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    dollars = get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
    left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)

    print("Total = %s$" % total_value)
    print("You have"+ str(dollars) + "dollars and"+ str(left_over_cents)+ "cent(s)")

def get_input(currency):
    currency = 0
    if currency < 0:
        print('Cannot have negative money')
    else:
        return currency


def get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    return (float(pennies) * .01) + (float(nickels) * .05) + (float(dimes) * .10) + (float(quarters) * .25)

def get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    return 1

main()
```

**EDIT:**

> "I need to create a function that returns a total of dollar amount."

`return` was missing in your function `get_total`

The above code should be working